# Не работают shortcode

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Joomla 3. Прикрутил возможность добавлять текстовые описания к тегам компонента CKK K2 Joomla. Реализовано аналогично тому, как сделано описание для категорий по умолчанию в данном компоненте. Все сохраняется в бд и корректно выводится в шаблоне вывода материалов по тегу.

Но не работают плагины шорткодов - ни плагин Sourcer, ни Widgetkit ни другие аналогичные.

Например при вставке в форму текстового редактора в админпанели `[widgetkit id="1" name="1"]` во фронтэнде мы получаем просто надпись `[widgetkit id="1" name="1"]`. При вставке `{source}"код"{/source}` - сам код вырезается редактором. При вставке `[module-1]` от RockIngectModule снова во фронтенде получаем текст `[module-1]`, а не сам модуль.

С другими плагинами и компонентами такая же ситуация.

Разумеется во всех иных местах (материалы, категории, модули и т.д.) плагины отрабатывают хорошо и проблем нигде нет. Проблема только в том месте, где я прикрутил форму текстового редактора. При смене редактора проблема не меняется.

Скажите пожалуйста что я мог упустить? Кто знает как решить проблему?

Возможность добавлять описание для тегов к2 реализовывал аналогично тому, как [описано здесь](http://webmasters.ru/forum/f132/joomla-plagin-upravleniya-tegami-k-66442/#post698310).